# google visualization conflict in an ajax page

Tags: jquery, google-visualization

This code works fine in a standalone page. I am pulling this code via jquery ajax into another page and it does not display the chart. I have searched and searched and not found the answer.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
      ['Data Entry', 2],
      ['Filing', 1],
      ['Social Media', 2],
      ['Email Responses', 1],
      ['Customer Care', 2]
    ]);

    var options = {
      chartArea:{left:20,top:0,width:"80%",height:"70%"},
      legend: {position: 'left', textStyle: {fontSize: 14}},
      is3D: 'true'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
</script>



    <div id="chart_div" style="position: relative; z-index: 100; width: 580px; height: 400px; margin: 0px 0px 0px 50px; border: overflow: hidden;">
    </div>
```

Appreciate any assistance anyone can provide, thanks.

Comment: Hi, are you able to provide any of the extra details I asked for ?